# Start and End of Text file parsing with some conditions

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

I have a list of start_phrases and stop_phrase.

I want to parse the file and write to output file as below:
If I see the line contains ONLY start_phrases, I want to start writing/appending start_phrase to output file. And then continue to append the  consecutive lines to output file.

When the line starts with the stop_phrases, then I want to stop parsing and break the loop. I don't want to append the stop_phrase to the output.

```
start_phrases = ["Hello", "Come on:", "Introduction", "Background"]
stop_phrases = ["This is provided to assist", "The background knowledge is to know"]
```

I am reading a file as below.

```
with open (data, "r", encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        line.strip()
            print(line)
```

How to include these conditions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex expressions:

```py
import re

start_phrases = ["Hello", "Come on:", "Introduction", "Background"]
stop_phrases = ["This is provided to assist", "The background knowledge is to know"]

start_regex = re.compile(f'(?i)^\s*({"|".join(start_phrases)})\s*$')
stop_regex = re.compile(f'(?i)^\s*({"|".join(stop_phrases)})\s*$')

parse = False
with open (data, "r", encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if  stop_regex.match(line):
            break

        parse = parse or start_regex.match(line)
        if parse:
            print(line)
```

You can create a regex to find start sentences and another for stop sentences.

The bool `parse` keeps the status: if it is `True`, the current line is parsed, otherwise is skipped.

Suppose that the content of the input file is:

```
aaaa
Hello WOrld
Hello
cccc
dddd
This is provided to assist gre
bbbb
This is provided to assist
kkkk
pppppp
```

the output is:

```bash
Hello

cccc

dddd

This is provided to assist gre

bbbb
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for not writng clearly. I want to parse and write as below: If I see the line contains ONLY start_phrases, I want to start writing them to output file. And then continue to append the output file. When the line starts with the stop_phrases, then I want to stop parsing and break the loop.